# Swagger Editor - declare request json body fields as formData, but send these as json

Tags: json, node.js, forms, swagger-editor

I'm using latest Swagger Editor, and my server api accepted just json body requests, but if you declare parameter with formData docs will be clearly for developer. My question: How to I can declare parameter as formData but when try it send json body request. I tried Swagger Editor oldest version 2.9.6 and declare parameter as formData and declare "produces" and "consumes" as "application/json" then if i try it on the editor works, but if I generate nodejs-server and try it will send content-type is form-url-encoding, look to following screenshots:

[image]
[image]

If I generate nodejs-server, not works:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to I can declare parameter as formData but when try it send json body request.

You can't. The API specification is a contract between the client and server and is supposed to precisely define the server behavior. If the server expects JSON, the specification must use `in: body` parameters and not `in: formData`. If the server works in one way and the spec states another way, it's useless.

If you want to use `formData` parameters in the spec, change your server to accept form data and write the spec accordingly.